# Sum of the series $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^{2n}}{n\cdot2^n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty  \frac{x^{2n}}{n\cdot2^n}=?$$

I can find $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty  \frac{x^{n}}{n\cdot2^n}$$,but how i get $x^{2n}$ from that?

Comment: Replace $x$ by $x^2$.

Comment: This is a [polylogarithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm).

Comment: we didn't learn about special functions(maybe we mentioned one or two...),but i can replace x with everything,that makes no problem?

Comment: @Lucian Sure, with poly = mono...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> (2018-11-25) "Amusing" revenge downvote, four years later.

You know that
$$\sum_{n\geqslant1}\frac1nt^n=-\log(1-t)
$$
and you are asking about
$$\sum_{n\geqslant1}\frac{x^{2n}}{n2^n}=\sum_{n\geqslant1}\frac1n\left(\frac{x^2}2\right)^n=-\log\left(1-\ldots\right).
$$